# Multi Index table local instance

Tags: multi-index

I am creating a local instance of multi index table (following the example given in this tutorial: https://developers.eos.io/eosio-cpp/docs/using-multi-index-tables) but when I try to compile I get the following error:

***error: use of undeclared identifier '_ktcusers'***

On line: `auto user_iterator = _ktcusers.find(user.value);`

Not sure what I am missing.  My code below:

```
#include <eosiolib/eosio.hpp>
#include <eosiolib/print.hpp>

using namespace eosio;

class [[eosio::contract]] ktc : public eosio::contract {

public:

    ktc( eosio::name receiver, eosio::name code,  eosio::datastream<const char*> ds ): eosio::contract(receiver, code, ds), _ktcusers(receiver, code.value) {}

    [[eosio::action]] void upsert(name user);

    struct [[eosio::table]] ktcuser {
      name key;
      std::string first_name;
      std::string last_name;
      std::string street;
      std::string city;
      std::string state;
      uint64_t primary_key() const { return key.value; }
    };

    typedef eosio::multi_index<"ktcuser"_n, ktcuser> ktcusers;

    //local instance of multi index table
    ktcusers _ktcusers;
}

#include "ktc.hpp"

void upsert(name user) {

    // Ensure this action is authorized by the player
    require_auth(user);

    // Create a record in the table
    auto user_iterator = _ktcusers.find(user.value);
    if (user_iterator == _ktcusers.end()) {
        user_iterator = _ktcusers.emplace(user,  [&](auto& new_user) {
        new_user.key = user;
    });
  }

  }


EOSIO_DISPATCH( ktc, (login))
```

Comment: Well after spending a lot of time on this, all I can say for certain is that the primary index of the multi index container must be a uint64_t per the docs, and that the contract's file name must match the class declaration name.

Comment: in ktc.cpp ```void upsert(name user)``` -> ```void ktc::upsert(name user)```.
```EOSIO_DISPATCH( ktc, (login))``` -> ```EOSIO_DISPATCH( ktc, (upsert))```

Comment: Chaging void upsert(name user) to void ktc::upsert(name user) did the trick.  It compiled now.  Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per Cooper Goldcrest's suggestion, changing

```
void upsert(name user)
```

TO

```
void ktc::upsert(name user)
```

in my .cpp file solved the issue.  My header file contained all the declarations and so ktc::upsert worked.